# How to change a Youtube video on <li> click?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I'm attempting to change the video playing in my  embed. I would like to know if this can be done by clicking on an LI item?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) javascrip library to add an onclick event to your `<li>`.

```
$('li').click(function() {
    var newId = $(this).text(); 
    player.loadVideoById(newId, 0, "large");
});
```

If the video is inside the `<li>` you might need to create a transparent overlay that reacts to the user clicking. Note that you might have to change the z-index of the iframe.

Please provide more info on your page layout if you require more help.

Comment: I was looking into this code: http://jsfiddle.net/d5rca/ and was wondering if there was a way to use this.

Comment: Have you read this [link]https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Queueing_Functions[/link]? Call it with player object like `player.loadVideoById(newId, 0, "large");`.